# ¿Por qué sucede esto después de ejecutar Rails Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

- Uso windows10 como entorno de desarrollo
- Como no tengo acceso a SQLITE3 al crear un nuevo proyecto uso el siguiente comando `Rails new myapp -d mysql`
- Uso Ruby on Rails 5.2.3 y Ruby 2.5.5p157

El error que me aparece es el siguiente: Al parecer realiza la misma acción dos veces

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.5-p157), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop

   (25.0ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
   (1.0ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
  ↳ C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  ↳ C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
```

Mientras que en el navegador no se muestra ningún error. Antes cuando tenia las versiones anteriores todo era normal. Ayúdenme por favor esto es un gran obstáculo y quiero aprender. Muchos me han dicho que es mejor desarrollar con IOS pero económicamente me es imposible obtenerla. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido, Ruby on Rails corre mejor en entornos GNU/Linux y Mac. En Windows anda medio buggeado

Comment: Yo no lo veo como error. ¿a que te refieres que no te salía cuando tenías las versiones anteriores? ¿hay algo que no funcione debido a eso? ¿en que momento te sale? ¿al iniciar tu server? ¿al hacer un request específico? ¿podrías agregar el log completo de el momento en el cual te sale y bajo qué acción? si es bajo un request, además agrega el código relevante. Si es al iniciar el server, quizás sería bueno ver si alguna gema

Comment: @AlterLagos , este problema sucede después de iniciar el server y al ingresar a la pagina principal **localhost:3000**, hay momentos donde arranca normal pero otros no _(se queda estancado en esa parte)_. a que se debe?

Comment: @fredyfx asi me han dicho que corre mejor en Linux y Mac, recién estoy aprendiendo con este framework de ruby, soy muy novato, pero tengo una duda si solo corre "bien" en linux y mac, que pasa cuando deseo usar el producto terminado en una pc windows, perdona mi mega ignorancia. ¿Que pasa cuando el sistema en producción lo deseo correr en una pc con windows?

Comment: No es que corra mal en linux, es simplemente que ciertos comandos o librerías que rails o gemas que puedas usar no se encuentran disponibles en sistemas no unix-like. Puedes encontrar más motivos en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166548/895789). Respecto a ejecutar el sistema en producción en windows server o algo similar, eso prácticamente no existe. La gran mayoría de servidores en el mundo funcionan con Linux. Es sabido que el rendimiento es mejor, manejo de recursos, seguridad y un gran etcetera. Incluso Azure, sistema cloud de Microsoft, ofrecen Linux para deploy de apps.

Comment: Una razón de peso para usar windows como sistema en producción sería que estés desarrollando para .NET u otro framework desarrollado por windows. Incluso así mono (versión open source de .NET que funciona en linux) ha progresado bastante por lo que tengo entendido. En fin, mi punto es que, si, puedes usar windows para desarrollar en rails, pero si quieres tener menos problemas de compatibilidad o asemejarte lo más posible a lo que sería tu sistema final funcionando en producción, lo mejor sería que uses Linux o IOS. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

La consulta que ves se origina [en este método](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L739), donde simplemente configura la conexión a tu instancia de MySQL, no hay nada de malo con ese mensaje.
Si estás viendo esa información, es por [`verbose_query_logs`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#verbose-query-logs) introducido en [Rails 5.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26815/files#diff-1ed2907b3b8f148c2533558a77673ffa). Si quieres desactivarlo, puedes entrar en `config/environments/development.rb` y hacerlo, ya que viene activado por defecto para entorno de desarrollo.
Si tu servidor se queda estancado como dices, debe ser por otra razón, pero no por lo que mencionas. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder. Con respecto a que el servidor se queda estancado, cuales podrían ser los motivos más comunes en windows, **¿podría ser por el puerto? ¿Por el firewall? o ¿por el rendimiento de la pc?**

Comment: @ArellanoCornejoDaniel Nunca he programado rails en windows, además con la información que entregas no es suficiente para darte una respuesta clara. No creo que sea problema de puerto. Si estuviese ya ocupado, la aplicación ni siquiera iniciaría. El firewall es para conexiones hacia afuera de tu red, tu estás ejecutando la app de tu localhost, así que no debería ser ese el problema. Podrías revisar el uso de cpu o memoria de tu pc mientras está corriendo tu app rails. Por lo que das a entender esto no te sucede siempre, quizás tenga que ver con algo externo a la aplicación en sí.